# What statistical tests can be used on a distribution of distributions?

Tags: distributions, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, paired-comparisons

I have two experimental conditions, each with 20 reps (40 experiments total). In all 40 experiments a non-fixed number of sounds were recorded, and I've measured each of their durations. I would now like to test the null hypothesis that, on average, the sound durations in condition A are the same as in condition B. However, I'm a little unsure how to do this in a way that captures all of the data. 
***I should note that I have the same data format for a number of pairs of conditions A and B, and sometimes the data are paired and sometimes they are not paired. I'm struggling with both data types.

My current ideas are:

1. Pool all of the measurements from each condition into two giant distributions and do a t-test (I'm going to ignore the question of parametric vs. non-parametric testing for simplicity's sake). This seems reasonable, but in the paired case it ignores the pattern between the two conditions across individuals.
2. Reduce each distribution to a measure of central tendency and then do a t-test on the distributions of MoCTs. This seems a bit fishy, as it doesn't really take into account most of the data in the raw data distributions, but it does work equally well in both the paired and the unpaired data conditions.
3. In the paired data condition, do individual t-tests between each pair of paired data, then do a t-test to see if the resulting distribution of t-stats is different from 0 (which would indicate that in some pairs the sound durations were longer in condition A and in some cases they were longer in condition B, but across the population of pairs there isn't a strong pattern in one direction or the other). I feel that this scheme does the best at taking all of the data into account, but I don't know how to do something equivalent with the unpaired data.